# how to do a mock test with polymer

Tags: javascript, testing, mocking, polymer

I have a function, is a function of polymer web component custom.

```js
    getListDedications: function(e){
            var idDate = e.model.__data__.date.data.id;
            var checkId = function(element){
              return element.id == idDate;
            };
            var responseID = this.dedications.filter(checkId);
            this.data = JSON.stringify(responseID[0].entries) || [];
            console.log(JSON.stringify(responseID[0].entries) || []);
    }
```

This function return a array or an array empty.

I want to test it, I'm using web-component-tester and I run the tests with `gulp test:local`.
I know that I need to mock `e.model.__data__.date.data.id` but I do not know how

Answer (score 0):

Web component tester comes with sinon and sinon-chai bundled in it now.

You don't say what e.model._data__.date.date.id is.  Obviously if its just data, you set it up and then call getListModifications with the a parameter.  However, if its a function then use sinon stub (or spy) with

```
var sandbox;
beforeEach(function(){
  sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
});
afterEach(function(){
  sandbox.restore();
});
it('should ...',function(){
  var e = sandbox.stub().returns('whatever data you want');
  var answer = getListDedications(e);
  expect(answer).to.be.an('Array');
});
```